# how to convert restassured's httpheaders to a map of <string, string>?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I want to convert restassured's httpheaders to a map and then use its specific values. can someone please help me here?

Here is my code -

```
private void executerequest(String uri, HttpHeaders requestHeader){
..todo..
}
```

now as a part of this fuction, I want the map which contains key value pair for httpheaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the `HttpHeaders` object and extract its key-value pairs into a `Map`. As you can see here:

```
import io.restassured.http.Headers;
import io.restassured.http.Header;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

private void executeRequest(String uri, Headers requestHeaders) {
    Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Header header : requestHeaders) {
        headerMap.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `void` it would be better to return `Map<String, String>` from your method.